# How can i optimize this query which is taking much time?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query which is taking around 40-50 seconds to load

```
SELECT
  members.latitude,
  members.longitude,
  members.mem_id
FROM members
WHERE profile_type != "C"
    AND (gender = 'm'
          OR gender = 'f')
    AND members.mem_id IN(SELECT DISTINCT
                            n2.mem_id
                          FROM network n1,
                            network n2
                          WHERE n1.frd_id = n2.mem_id
                              AND n1.mem_id = '48'
                              AND n2.frd_id = '48')
ORDER BY profilenam
```

there is network table which contains users friends

Please help..

Comment: there are already index added in both the tables

Comment: @user1551419 `AND (gender = 'm'
          OR gender = 'f')` this part seems to be extra (unless there's another possibility).

Comment: some logic clarification - `(gender = 'm' OR gender = 'f')` what else can be?

Comment: Using != is not particularly efficient, try changing it to profile_type in ( ... ) if there are many variations or just profile_type = 'A' etc. if not

Comment: no this has to be there because user can search by gender itself

Comment: Presumably gender can be null, which means "not specified".

Comment: `WHERE n1.frd_id = n2.mem_id AND n1.mem_id = '48' AND n2.frd_id = '48')` -> `WHERE n1.frd_id = n2.mem_id AND n1.mem_id = 48)`

Comment: Could you post your schema and some test data to http://sqlfiddle.com/? The problem is the dependend subquery in your WHERE, need to be replaced with something, most likely joins. Add an `explain` before your query to see where its taking its time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is slow because of the sub-query used try it without sub-query using derived table:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, a.mem_id
FROM members a
     INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT n2.mem_id AS mem_id
                 FROM network n1,
                      network n2
                 WHERE n1.frd_id = n2.mem_id
                       AND n1.mem_id = '48'
                       AND n2.frd_id = '48'
                ) b
                ON a.mem_id = b.mem_id
WHERE profile_type != "C"
      AND (gender = 'm'
           OR gender = 'f')
ORDER BY profilenam;
```

Also add proper indexes on table and use `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` to check for index usage:

```
ALTER TABLE network ADD KEY ix1(mem_id);
ALTER TABLE network ADD KEY ix1(frd_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The IN clause is only really suitable if the result set is small. For a larger result set, consider rewriting the query. Filters (which an IN clause generates) are an expensive database operation.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the IN clause with EXISTS.

There is only 1000 item allowed in the IN collection

in(items_num=1000)